# Write a function to list all possible combinations of models

Tags: r, function, regression, lm

I'm attempting to write a function to run all possible regression models for variables in a dataset. I was able to get it to run each variable, this is what I have so far.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
data("mtcars")
```

```
model1 <- function (DATA) {
DATA %>%
  map(~lm(mpg ~ .x, data = DATA), tidy)%>%   map(summary) %>% 
  map_dbl("adj.r.squared") %>%
  tidy %>% 
  rename(adj.r.squared = x)
}

model1(mtcars)
```

I am new to R and writing functions so I am sure there are some issues with it. I want a tibble of all the adjusted r squared values for all possible models. How do I write a function that will do the same thing for two, three, or more variables?

Comment: Do you mean you want to run an ordinary least squares regression on all possible subsets of input variables of the data set?

Comment: While that is possible it's advisable to reconsider, pragmatically because it becomes prohibitive as the number of predictors or runtime of the model increases and from a  statistical background; you should include all variables you think may be predictive. If they are - good - if they are not - their effect size will be small

Comment: I want all possible subsets.

Comment: Not a good idea, but look at function `ols_step_all_possible` in package `olsrr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any packages that allow one to automate this. So, let's try a brute force approach. The idea is to generate all possible combinations by hand and iterate over them.

```
vars <- names(mtcars)[-1]

models <- list()

for (i in 1:5){
  vc <- combn(vars,i)
  for (j in 1:ncol(vc)){
    model <- as.formula(paste0("mpg ~", paste0(vc[,j], collapse = "+")))
    models <- c(models, model)
  }
}
```

You can use these formulas for run the linear model.

```
lapply(models, function(x) lm(x, data = mtcars))
```