# Writing a function to build a list of all possible models where each variable has multiple types of regressions

Tags: r, function, regression, modeling

I'd like to build off of this pretty clean way to build a list of all possible models:
[Write a function to list all possible models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883747/write-a-function-to-list-all-possible-combinations-of-models)

My problem is that I'd like to be able to set each variable to have multiple regression types. For example, I'd like to be able to test:

```
x
s(x)
plogis(x)
poly(x,2)
poly(x,3)
```

I've adapted the code from the answer above to be able to run as a function from a few inputs:

```
step_gam <- function (dependent, var_list, data) {
  vars <- list()
  for(n in 1:length(var_list)){
    vars[[n]] = list(paste(var_list[n]), 
                     paste("s(",var_list[n],")"), 
                     paste("plogis(",var_list[n],")"), 
                     paste("Poly(",var_list[n],",2)"), 
                     paste("Poly(",var_list[n],",3)"))
  }

  vars <- unlist(vars)
  models <- list()

  for (i in 1:length(vars)){
    vc <- combn(vars,i)
    for (j in 1:ncol(vc)){
      model <- as.formula(paste0(dependent, "~", paste0(vc[,j], collapse = "+")))
      models <- c(models, model)
    }
  }

  lapply(models, function (x) gam(x, data = data))
}
var_list <- c("EstimatedAge")

step_gam("prop_transit", var_list, weekly_stb_gam)
```

The only issue is that currently, the function loops back through each variable, so even if I only have 1 term, I end up with 31 models, not 5.

example of the current output for object `models`:

```
y~x
y~x + s(x)
y~x + s(x) + plogis(x)
...
```

What I'd like to be able to do is include each variable only once. 
example of expected output for object `models`:

```
y~x
y~s(x)
y~plogis(x)
```

But, I have multiple variables:
example of expected output for object `models`

```
y ~ x
y ~ z
y ~ x + z
y ~ s(x)
y ~ s(z)
y ~ s(x) + z
y ~ x + s(z)
y ~ s(x) + s(z)
```

weekly_stb_gam
dput:

```
structure(list(EstimatedAge = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), woy = c(49L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 6L, 37L, 10L, 36L, 44L, 11L, 24L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 28L, 31L, 41L, 45L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 16L, 18L, 
19L, 22L, 27L, 28L, 32L, 35L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 49L, 3L, 5L, 19L, 
20L, 22L, 28L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 51L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 
14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 33L, 36L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
29L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L), at_large = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 21L, 27L, 6L, 12L, 21L, 24L, 26L, 21L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 25L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 27L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 24L, 26L, 22L, 23L, 
20L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Avg_Flow = c(5468.14285714286, 
7159.28571428571, 3200.28571428571, 6569.71428571429, 6975, 6374.57142857143, 
7077, 7172.42857142857, 7171.28571428571, 7167.57142857143, 1490.85714285714, 
4373.85714285714, 2424.28571428571, 3429.85714285714, 2378.28571428571, 
1003.28571428571, 644.857142857143, 3208.28571428571, 693.428571428571, 
1126.14285714286, 1406.57142857143, 4852.85714285714, 4635.42857142857, 
989.285714285714, 2135.85714285714, 920.285714285714, 378, 1487.85714285714, 
2495.14285714286, 1937, 493.714285714286, 412.857142857143, 190.428571428571, 
374.428571428571, 1184.85714285714, 1190.57142857143, 2190, 2419.57142857143, 
2001.28571428571, 291.571428571429, 1288.42857142857, 5468.14285714286, 
3861.42857142857, 2534.28571428571, 326.714285714286, 535.285714285714, 
606.285714285714, 246.857142857143, 342.571428571429, 346, 2323.28571428571, 
762.857142857143, 464.571428571429, 1567.14285714286, 2464, 2536.42857142857, 
2389.28571428571, 2331.28571428571, 498, 513.571428571429, 1164.85714285714, 
1307.71428571429, 4135.85714285714, 6417.85714285714, 7159.28571428571, 
7077, 7167.57142857143, 1804.28571428571, 2047.71428571429, 6250.28571428571, 
5450.71428571429, 4564.28571428571, 4994.14285714286, 5268.71428571429, 
6639.14285714286, 6953.71428571429, 5281.85714285714, 3636.57142857143, 
3423.14285714286, 1993.71428571429, 1350.42857142857, 824.142857142857, 
1309, 2493.85714285714, 1851.71428571429, 1366.28571428571, 1404.57142857143, 
1365.14285714286, 1906.28571428571, 1993.85714285714, 1444.57142857143, 
1122.42857142857, 1492.71428571429, 663.714285714286, 721.285714285714, 
2517.85714285714, 922.142857142857, 835.285714285714, 906.857142857143, 
492.142857142857), Avg_Temperature = c(14.5571428571429, 24.2285714285714, 
24.4571428571429, 25.3714285714286, 25.3857142857143, 24.3857142857143, 
24.7, 23.7571428571429, 22.4857142857143, 22.6428571428571, 23.9428571428571, 
13.6, 22.8142857142857, 15.9714285714286, 24.6714285714286, 17.5142857142857, 
18.5142857142857, 23, 19.9, 22.9, 24.5285714285714, 25.2571428571429, 
23.8142857142857, 18.1857142857143, 15.1428571428571, 9.58571428571429, 
11.5571428571429, 11.8571428571429, 13.6285714285714, 14.5285714285714, 
19.9714285714286, 20.7857142857143, 20.6428571428571, 23.5285714285714, 
26.1857142857143, 26.1571428571429, 25.7428571428571, 25.1, 22.8285714285714, 
20.6142857142857, 17.1571428571429, 14.5571428571429, 10.6142857142857, 
11.8285714285714, 20.1571428571429, 19.4285714285714, 22.5, 24.2714285714286, 
25.0142857142857, 24.4142857142857, 24.6142857142857, 23.6714285714286, 
22.9571428571429, 9.77142857142857, 8.31428571428571, 9.21428571428571, 
14.6142857142857, 16.0571428571429, 18.4428571428571, 19.1857142857143, 
19.8285714285714, 20.0857142857143, 23.0142857142857, 25.0857142857143, 
24.2285714285714, 24.7, 22.6428571428571, 22.8714285714286, 22.7857142857143, 
26.3714285714286, 26.2571428571429, 24.7571428571429, 24.4142857142857, 
23.4714285714286, 24.9, 24.1571428571429, 24.0714285714286, 24.0142857142857, 
21.7142857142857, 20.0285714285714, 18.5571428571429, 18.4, 17.46, 
15.18, 14.6, 12.6857142857143, 12.0285714285714, 8.87142857142857, 
8.34285714285714, 8.58571428571429, 8.65714285714286, 8.98571428571429, 
9.87142857142857, 10.7857142857143, 14.3571428571429, 16.5714285714286, 
17.3571428571429, 16.3142857142857, 17.3714285714286, 19.8428571428571
), Avg_Turbidity = c(5.99857142857143, 11.0457142857143, 24.9557142857143, 
11.02, 8.63285714285714, 8.62571428571429, 9.84714285714286, 
9.91714285714286, 8.31571428571429, 7.93142857142857, 7.34428571428571, 
6.58285714285714, 10.2442857142857, 9.04285714285714, 8.57571428571429, 
3.69142857142857, 6.71285714285714, 9.22285714285714, 17.6685714285714, 
14.6685714285714, 13.5242857142857, 13.0742857142857, 19.3942857142857, 
9.04428571428571, 7.74285714285714, 8.15428571428571, 9.22571428571429, 
9.17857142857143, 8.56285714285714, 9.18857142857143, 8.43428571428571, 
7.8, 8.91857142857143, 7.99, 11.69, 11.42, 14.1371428571429, 
9.30857142857143, 6.42428571428571, 3.93, 4.21857142857143, 5.99857142857143, 
10.71, 6.77285714285714, 8.67, 8.87571428571428, 7.26285714285714, 
9.11285714285714, 10.0828571428571, 10.6071428571429, 9.18, 6.09857142857143, 
5.55571428571429, 8.71, 8.13, 9.99857142857143, 12.805, 9.59666666666667, 
12.2728571428571, 12.4328571428571, 7.57, 8.03714285714286, 10.5885714285714, 
11.4442857142857, 11.0457142857143, 9.84714285714286, 7.93142857142857, 
13.8442857142857, 16.9785714285714, 14.8142857142857, 13.8042857142857, 
16.63, 20.01, 11.8728571428571, 9.90571428571429, 12.34, 64.4071428571429, 
10.9714285714286, 10.3914285714286, 10.07, 10.5142857142857, 
7.41142857142857, 7.122, 7.942, 11.9171428571429, 8.47142857142857, 
7.97857142857143, 8.00714285714286, 8.08142857142857, 9.42857142857143, 
8.95571428571429, 8.38714285714286, 8.46428571428572, 8.22428571428572, 
8.12142857142857, 9.46714285714286, 9.14285714285714, 35.4285714285714, 
8.88, 8.37714285714286), n_Salmonids = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 43, 0, 0, 7, 0, 86, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 5, 12, 104, 22, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 17, 13, 93, 21, 7, 12, 13, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 43, 17, 17, 85, 33)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L))
> dput(weekly_stb_gam[1:100,c(4:10,13)])
structure(list(EstimatedAge = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), woy = c(49L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 6L, 37L, 10L, 36L, 44L, 11L, 24L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 28L, 31L, 41L, 45L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 16L, 18L, 
19L, 22L, 27L, 28L, 32L, 35L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 49L, 3L, 5L, 19L, 
20L, 22L, 28L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 51L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 
14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 33L, 36L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
29L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L), at_large = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 21L, 27L, 6L, 12L, 21L, 24L, 26L, 21L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 25L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 27L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 24L, 26L, 22L, 23L, 
20L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Avg_Flow = c(5468.14285714286, 
7159.28571428571, 3200.28571428571, 6569.71428571429, 6975, 6374.57142857143, 
7077, 7172.42857142857, 7171.28571428571, 7167.57142857143, 1490.85714285714, 
4373.85714285714, 2424.28571428571, 3429.85714285714, 2378.28571428571, 
1003.28571428571, 644.857142857143, 3208.28571428571, 693.428571428571, 
1126.14285714286, 1406.57142857143, 4852.85714285714, 4635.42857142857, 
989.285714285714, 2135.85714285714, 920.285714285714, 378, 1487.85714285714, 
2495.14285714286, 1937, 493.714285714286, 412.857142857143, 190.428571428571, 
374.428571428571, 1184.85714285714, 1190.57142857143, 2190, 2419.57142857143, 
2001.28571428571, 291.571428571429, 1288.42857142857, 5468.14285714286, 
3861.42857142857, 2534.28571428571, 326.714285714286, 535.285714285714, 
606.285714285714, 246.857142857143, 342.571428571429, 346, 2323.28571428571, 
762.857142857143, 464.571428571429, 1567.14285714286, 2464, 2536.42857142857, 
2389.28571428571, 2331.28571428571, 498, 513.571428571429, 1164.85714285714, 
1307.71428571429, 4135.85714285714, 6417.85714285714, 7159.28571428571, 
7077, 7167.57142857143, 1804.28571428571, 2047.71428571429, 6250.28571428571, 
5450.71428571429, 4564.28571428571, 4994.14285714286, 5268.71428571429, 
6639.14285714286, 6953.71428571429, 5281.85714285714, 3636.57142857143, 
3423.14285714286, 1993.71428571429, 1350.42857142857, 824.142857142857, 
1309, 2493.85714285714, 1851.71428571429, 1366.28571428571, 1404.57142857143, 
1365.14285714286, 1906.28571428571, 1993.85714285714, 1444.57142857143, 
1122.42857142857, 1492.71428571429, 663.714285714286, 721.285714285714, 
2517.85714285714, 922.142857142857, 835.285714285714, 906.857142857143, 
492.142857142857), Avg_Temperature = c(14.5571428571429, 24.2285714285714, 
24.4571428571429, 25.3714285714286, 25.3857142857143, 24.3857142857143, 
24.7, 23.7571428571429, 22.4857142857143, 22.6428571428571, 23.9428571428571, 
13.6, 22.8142857142857, 15.9714285714286, 24.6714285714286, 17.5142857142857, 
18.5142857142857, 23, 19.9, 22.9, 24.5285714285714, 25.2571428571429, 
23.8142857142857, 18.1857142857143, 15.1428571428571, 9.58571428571429, 
11.5571428571429, 11.8571428571429, 13.6285714285714, 14.5285714285714, 
19.9714285714286, 20.7857142857143, 20.6428571428571, 23.5285714285714, 
26.1857142857143, 26.1571428571429, 25.7428571428571, 25.1, 22.8285714285714, 
20.6142857142857, 17.1571428571429, 14.5571428571429, 10.6142857142857, 
11.8285714285714, 20.1571428571429, 19.4285714285714, 22.5, 24.2714285714286, 
25.0142857142857, 24.4142857142857, 24.6142857142857, 23.6714285714286, 
22.9571428571429, 9.77142857142857, 8.31428571428571, 9.21428571428571, 
14.6142857142857, 16.0571428571429, 18.4428571428571, 19.1857142857143, 
19.8285714285714, 20.0857142857143, 23.0142857142857, 25.0857142857143, 
24.2285714285714, 24.7, 22.6428571428571, 22.8714285714286, 22.7857142857143, 
26.3714285714286, 26.2571428571429, 24.7571428571429, 24.4142857142857, 
23.4714285714286, 24.9, 24.1571428571429, 24.0714285714286, 24.0142857142857, 
21.7142857142857, 20.0285714285714, 18.5571428571429, 18.4, 17.46, 
15.18, 14.6, 12.6857142857143, 12.0285714285714, 8.87142857142857, 
8.34285714285714, 8.58571428571429, 8.65714285714286, 8.98571428571429, 
9.87142857142857, 10.7857142857143, 14.3571428571429, 16.5714285714286, 
17.3571428571429, 16.3142857142857, 17.3714285714286, 19.8428571428571
), Avg_Turbidity = c(5.99857142857143, 11.0457142857143, 24.9557142857143, 
11.02, 8.63285714285714, 8.62571428571429, 9.84714285714286, 
9.91714285714286, 8.31571428571429, 7.93142857142857, 7.34428571428571, 
6.58285714285714, 10.2442857142857, 9.04285714285714, 8.57571428571429, 
3.69142857142857, 6.71285714285714, 9.22285714285714, 17.6685714285714, 
14.6685714285714, 13.5242857142857, 13.0742857142857, 19.3942857142857, 
9.04428571428571, 7.74285714285714, 8.15428571428571, 9.22571428571429, 
9.17857142857143, 8.56285714285714, 9.18857142857143, 8.43428571428571, 
7.8, 8.91857142857143, 7.99, 11.69, 11.42, 14.1371428571429, 
9.30857142857143, 6.42428571428571, 3.93, 4.21857142857143, 5.99857142857143, 
10.71, 6.77285714285714, 8.67, 8.87571428571428, 7.26285714285714, 
9.11285714285714, 10.0828571428571, 10.6071428571429, 9.18, 6.09857142857143, 
5.55571428571429, 8.71, 8.13, 9.99857142857143, 12.805, 9.59666666666667, 
12.2728571428571, 12.4328571428571, 7.57, 8.03714285714286, 10.5885714285714, 
11.4442857142857, 11.0457142857143, 9.84714285714286, 7.93142857142857, 
13.8442857142857, 16.9785714285714, 14.8142857142857, 13.8042857142857, 
16.63, 20.01, 11.8728571428571, 9.90571428571429, 12.34, 64.4071428571429, 
10.9714285714286, 10.3914285714286, 10.07, 10.5142857142857, 
7.41142857142857, 7.122, 7.942, 11.9171428571429, 8.47142857142857, 
7.97857142857143, 8.00714285714286, 8.08142857142857, 9.42857142857143, 
8.95571428571429, 8.38714285714286, 8.46428571428572, 8.22428571428572, 
8.12142857142857, 9.46714285714286, 9.14285714285714, 35.4285714285714, 
8.88, 8.37714285714286), n_Salmonids = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 43, 0, 0, 7, 0, 86, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 5, 12, 104, 22, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 17, 13, 93, 21, 7, 12, 13, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 43, 17, 17, 85, 33), prop_transit = c(NaN, 
NaN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0476190476190476, 0.037037037037037, 
0.333333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0952380952380952, 0.0416666666666667, 
0.0384615384615385, 0.0476190476190476, NaN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 
0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get all possible terms in your formula per variable, and then arrange every combination of these terms. That includes an "empty" term.

I made a function to generate formulas based on your inputs.

Be careful, the more variables you have, **the number of formulas grows exponentially !**

```
mk_formulas <- function (dependent, var_list) {
  nvars <- length(var_list)

  vars <- lapply(var_list, function(v){
    possible_terms <- list("", # empty term
                           paste0(v), 
                           paste0("s(",v,")"), 
                           paste0("plogis(",v,")"), 
                           paste0("Poly(",v,", 2)"), 
                           paste0("Poly(",v,", 3)"))
  })
  vars <- do.call(cbind, vars)
  possible_combinations <- expand.grid(rep(list(seq_len(nrow(vars))), nvars)) 

  f_list <- apply(possible_combinations, 1, function(cmb) {
    keep <- cmb != 1 # remove empty terms
    coords <- cbind(cmb[keep], seq_len(nvars)[keep]) # get combination of terms
    return(paste(vars[coords], collapse = "+")) # paste
    })

  f_list <- lapply(f_list[-1], function(f) paste0(dependent, " ~ ", f))
  return(do.call(rbind, f_list))
}
```

To test it out :

```
var_list1 <- list("x")
var_list2 <- as.list(letters[24:25])
var_list3 <- as.list(letters[24:26])

mk_formulas("dep", var_list = var_list1)
# [,1]              
# [1,] "dep ~ x"         
# [2,] "dep ~ s(x)"      
# [3,] "dep ~ plogis(x)" 
# [4,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 2)"
# [5,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 3)"
mk_formulas("dep", var_list = var_list2)
# [,1]                         
# [1,] "dep ~ x"                    
# [2,] "dep ~ s(x)"                 
# [3,] "dep ~ plogis(x)"            
# [4,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 2)"           
# [5,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 3)"           
# [6,] "dep ~ y"                    
# [7,] "dep ~ x+y"                  
# [8,] "dep ~ s(x)+y"               
# [9,] "dep ~ plogis(x)+y"          
# [10,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 2)+y"         
# [11,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 3)+y"         
# [12,] "dep ~ s(y)"                 
# [13,] "dep ~ x+s(y)"               
# [14,] "dep ~ s(x)+s(y)"            
# [15,] "dep ~ plogis(x)+s(y)"       
# [16,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 2)+s(y)"      
# [17,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 3)+s(y)"      
# [18,] "dep ~ plogis(y)"            
# [19,] "dep ~ x+plogis(y)"          
# [20,] "dep ~ s(x)+plogis(y)"       
# [21,] "dep ~ plogis(x)+plogis(y)"  
# [22,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 2)+plogis(y)" 
# [23,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 3)+plogis(y)" 
# [24,] "dep ~ Poly(y, 2)"           
# [25,] "dep ~ x+Poly(y, 2)"         
# [26,] "dep ~ s(x)+Poly(y, 2)"      
# [27,] "dep ~ plogis(x)+Poly(y, 2)" 
# [28,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 2)+Poly(y, 2)"
# [29,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 3)+Poly(y, 2)"
# [30,] "dep ~ Poly(y, 3)"           
# [31,] "dep ~ x+Poly(y, 3)"         
# [32,] "dep ~ s(x)+Poly(y, 3)"      
# [33,] "dep ~ plogis(x)+Poly(y, 3)" 
# [34,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 2)+Poly(y, 3)"
# [35,] "dep ~ Poly(x, 3)+Poly(y, 3)"

# mk_formulas("dep", var_list = var_list3) # 215 formulas...
```